# Repeat view in a single activity

Tags: android

I have a activity which shows a button, a text and a list. I would like to repeat that pattern depending on data (SQLite). If I have 5 unique categories, show 5 buttons, 5 text and 5 lists. How do I do that ? How can I repeat the pattern ?

Answer (score -1):

in android you cannot "repeat a view" in a same actiivty (a child cannot have more than 1 parent ) but u can always do a workaround. u can write a mehod as getview() which returns u a parent view conatining ur buttons, texts etc. and u add this to the top layer viewgroup;

```
while(somelogic)

urparentview.addview(getview());

setcontentview(urparentview)
```

ur getviewmethod may be like this

```
  view getview()
    {
    button b = new button(this);
    edittext ed = new edittext(this);
    //set orientations etc...
    LinearLayout ll = new LineaLayout(this);
    ll.addview(b);
    ll.addView(ed);
    return ll;

    }
```

Comment: So I do not need a XML file for layout ?

Comment: button b = new button(this);b.setid(...);
is equivalent to 
button b = getviewyid(r.id.....);

Comment: pls mark this as an answer if this solved your problem, so it helps others with a similar problem :)

Answer (score -1):

You can just add a new button text and list to the same LinearLayout. So..

```
addStuffz(){
    LinearLayout main = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_linearLayout);
    LinearLayout newLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
    /**
     * Do Init here
     */
    Button anotherButton = new Button(context);
    /**
     * Do Init here
     */
    TextView anotherText = new TextView(context);
    /**
     * Do Init here
     */
    ListView anotherList = new ListView(context);
    /**
     * Do Init here
     */
    newLayout.addView(anotherButton);
    newLayout.addView(anotherText);
    newLayout.addView(anotherList);
    mainLayout.addView(newLayout);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The standard design pattern is to use a ListActivity(or a standard activity with a listView)
and create a CursorAdapter to create views and databind values from your recordset cursor to the view.

Then call setAdapter() on your ListActvity.

**VIDEO**

The use of list adapters is dicussed in the [Google IO 2009 video on UI improvements](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6YdwzAvwOA)